# Dts.Transaction is null in my SSIS Script task

Tags: ssis, script-task

I have tried existing post and none of the answers helped me solve the issue. Adding the piece of code.In the below code Dts.Transaction is null and hence 
sqlConn.

```
SqlConnection sqlConn;
sqlConn = (SqlConnection)(Dts.Connections["connectionManager"].AcquireConnection(Dts.Transaction) as SqlConnection);
sqlConn.Open();
```

I have an SQL Task which returns a list of records to Script Task. I am trying to use connection manager to establish a connection. Not sure what is wrong. It's ADO.net connection manager.

> Please do not mark this question as duplicate as the existing thread
>   did not help me.

Answer (score 0):

I have tested this and though `Dts.Transaction` is `null`, the following is working for me (also note that rather than opening/closing the connection, you use acquire/release):

```
SqlConnection sqlConn = (SqlConnection)Dts.Connections["connectionManager"].AcquireConnection(Dts.Transaction);

...

Dts.Connections["connectionManager"].ReleaseConnection(sqlConn);
```

Comment: I get below error. Message = "Keyword not supported: 'provider'." The connection manager was ADO.net connection. I reckon that's the issue. But not sure how to establish sql connection from that. Another option is changing connection manager (which I want to avoid)

Comment: Could you post the connection string?

Comment: The connection string is coming from the connection manager and it looks something like this.                                                                               
  Data Source=local;Initial Catalog=CatalogName;Provider=SQLNCLI11.1;Integrated Security=SSPI;Auto Translate=False;

Answer (score 0):

This here is working for me:

```
SqlConnection sqlCon = new SqlConnection();
sqlCon = (SqlConnection)Dts.Connections["DMP"].AcquireConnection(Dts.Transaction) as SqlConnection);
```